# How can I add a background image (CSS, not pattern) to a Highcharts column?

Tags: css, highcharts, background-image

I would like to add some CSS to all columns to position a background image properly, not like a pattern. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some of your code here please? Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Columns are genereted as objects in SVG / VML, not as HTML. So using CSS is not possible.